# Print the executed stored procedure in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have many stored procedures. I need to see the query which is being executed.

Is there any way I can print the stored procedure like other MySQL queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the stored procedure and use the Send To Editor or Send To Clipboard actions to get the create statement that was used to create the SP (similar for the other db objects).

[image]